# How to use LoggingBehaviour in Clean Architecture with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, architecture

I use [CleanArchitecture](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) for my .NET Core project with Angular and I am trying to use `LoggingBehaviour` class located on `CleanArchitecture/src/Application/Common/Behaviours/` in that project template as shown below:

```
namespace CleanArchitecture.Application.Common.Behaviours
{
    public class LoggingBehaviour<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest>
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
        private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

        public LoggingBehaviour(ILogger<TRequest> logger, ICurrentUserService currentUserService, 
            IIdentityService identityService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _currentUserService = currentUserService;
            _identityService = identityService;
        }

        public async Task Process(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var requestName = typeof(TRequest).Name;
            var userId = _currentUserService.UserId ?? string.Empty;
            string userName = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                userName = await _identityService.GetUserNameAsync(userId);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("CleanArchitecture Request: {Name} {@UserId} {@UserName} {@Request}",
                requestName, userId, userName, request);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have no idea about how to use it properly as there is not an example usage in that solution template. Could you please clarify me on how to use it properly according to [this](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) template example?

Comment: There is a `Behaviours/RequestLoggerTests.cs` it may covert the usage you need. in the test root

Comment: What are you try to use it for? This behavior is added in the [DependencyInjection](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Application/DependencyInjection.cs). It will only log the all the request. If you need to add custom log, where will it be ? Id that in all command/query in the application level ?  If that's the case it may look like the dbContext injection, You may inject it in the Infrastructure/DependencyInjection

Comment: @DragandDrop Thanks for reply. Actually I have not enough idea about that, but I think it would be used for logging all the user actions by also keeping userId. On the other hand, I think it may be possible to filter some events or actions for logging instead of logging all of them. Isn't it?

Comment: @DragandDrop On the other hand, could it be used for logging the exceptions? Os for that, should I use exception mechanishm in this Clean Architecture template?

Comment: For logging exeption you already have the `UnhandledExceptionBehaviour` and that is already injected. So lets go back a little and understand the "_Application.Common.Behaviours_" thing. We have request and we will produce response. On that we add some common behaviors. If the querry is slow, throw an error we log. we also had a behavior to handle roles and autorization. Now for that particular behavior. You will notice that it's not injected.  I do think that's a demo behavior. Use for demo.

Comment: For your question how should you log thing in the application layer, I will inject it like the db context.

Comment: There are some points that made me confused.

Comment: **1.** `UnhandledExceptionBehaviour` class has already its own `ILogger` definition and it seems to already log in case exception. Is that true?

Comment: **2.** However, what about the statuses except from exception? Forexample adding a log as an Info to say that the service is started. In this case I think I should imnject the ILogger to MyClass and log these info as following: `private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;` and `_logger.LogInformation($"Service has started");` Is that true?

Comment: **3.** In this case it is ok to use `_logger.LogError($"Got exception);` again in the `catch` block in MyClass? Or should I treat this logging in the exception block in UnhandledExceptionBehaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below;

```
namespace CleanArchitecture.Application.UnitTests.Common.Behaviours
{
    public class RequestLoggerTests
    {
        private readonly Mock<ILogger<CreateTodoItemCommand>> _logger;
        private readonly Mock<ICurrentUserService> _currentUserService;
        private readonly Mock<IIdentityService> _identityService;


        public RequestLoggerTests()
        {
            _logger = new Mock<ILogger<CreateTodoItemCommand>>();

            _currentUserService = new Mock<ICurrentUserService>();

            _identityService = new Mock<IIdentityService>();
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task ShouldCallGetUserNameAsyncOnceIfAuthenticated()
        {
            _currentUserService.Setup(x => x.UserId).Returns("Administrator");

            var requestLogger = new LoggingBehaviour<CreateTodoItemCommand>(_logger.Object, _currentUserService.Object, _identityService.Object);

            await requestLogger.Process(new CreateTodoItemCommand { ListId = 1, Title = "title" }, new CancellationToken());

            _identityService.Verify(i => i.GetUserNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task ShouldNotCallGetUserNameAsyncOnceIfUnauthenticated()
        {
            var requestLogger = new LoggingBehaviour<CreateTodoItemCommand>(_logger.Object, _currentUserService.Object, _identityService.Object);

            await requestLogger.Process(new CreateTodoItemCommand { ListId = 1, Title = "title" }, new CancellationToken());

            _identityService.Verify(i => i.GetUserNameAsync(null), Times.Never);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. As @DragandDrop said, is it used for logging all the user interactions? Or what is the purpose of this `LoggingBehaviour`?

Comment: Another question is that. I need to log for saving some information and errors on some lines e.g. after a process started and in case an exception is thrown. For this purpose, should I only use `ILogger` instead of this `LoggingBehaviour`?

Comment: I mean the example usage as shown on this: https://dev.azure.com/sergeydotnet/WorkerService/_git/SchedulingWorkerService?path=%2FDemoWorkerService%2FWorker.cs